# Android - ActionBar swipe tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-camera, swipe

I have an application which need 3 tabs, swipe tabs.

The first 2 are fragments and in the 3rd one i need to open the camera.

The fragments are titled as "Stream" "Profile" "Photo"
When the app is started the user should see the Stream fragment and when he swipes the view should change.

In order to start the camera when the user swipe or press the "Photo" tab, the photo class is extend the Activity class, and in onCreate I set an intent to start the camera.

The problem is when I swipe from "Stream" to "Profile" I see that its open the camera. When I debug this I see that when it happens, I mean, when I swipe from Stream to Profile, the listener returns the index of the camera tab.

It happens even if I change the photo class to extend the fragment..

So how can i start the camera just when the user press or swipe to "Photo" tab?

**Update:**

Ok now it's something weird.. i created a new project to see if there is something wrong with my code.. i just used the code from this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

**Update**

As the author of the tutorial did, I created the main activity which set all the tabs and the adapter and implements TabListener.
Now each tab is a class that extends from Fragment and have its own layout.
The main activity listen if there was a swipe and for what direction, or if tab was pressed right?
My tabs are in that order   `| STREAM | PROFILE | PHOTO |`
when the app is started I see the stream tab, when i move to profile tab (with pressing on the tab or just swipe) it shows me the right layout and marks the right tab but it enters to the onCreateView of the Photo tab. now if I in the Photo tab, and press the profile tab, it shows me the profile layout but enters to the onCreateView of the stream tab. it never enters to the onCreateView of the profile tab. why it happens? (I debugged it to see if it enters to the right onCreateView and what I described is the result)

The code is the same code in the tutorial.. I just changed the titles..

Answer (score 2):

Setting *mTabPager.[setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))* to *0* will not work because there is a limit 1. You can use "onPageChangeListener" instead and open camera intent when in camera tab.

```
mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Changed to page " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share some code, do you use FragmentStatePagerAdapter or FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: Did you try setOnPageChangeListener? Let me know if it worked

Comment: I used this, the tutorial is also use this.. ok, i will update the question and the problem to be more clearly